Rotate/Twist/Swirl points but using "distributed on faces" and a Length Property from center
What I want to create: A swirling particle galaxy, where the particles not only swirl globally, but also additionally rotate around a smaller axis, that also undulates on the z axis Reference of movement similar to the Sentinal swarms in the Matrix movie


Restraints: In the example I have used a Mesh to Points to illustrate the final look, what I need to use is a Distribute Points on Faces in combination of distance to center and a color ramp so I can control the overall radius of the galaxy as it swirls to its center.
What I have tried: I have tried to use a curve profile on a curve circle to generate the points on the smaller curve circle (Creating a Torus shape) and rotate the profile shape.
This works but.... the restriction I have is that I need to generate the points on a disk shape so I can build a swirling galaxy particle system and the above solve doesnt solve that workaround

Here is the animation reference mockup:



it would be helpful if you could link to a video/animation how it should look like.

Thank you Chris, I have added a mockup of the animation to show the particles rotating

so you wanna an additional rotation around the circles tangent, is that right? like this: [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/19ftOcM3.gif

So if i understood your right, you want to have an additional rotation around the tangent of the circle for each particle.
I don't add "additional" noise here, just to make it easier to understand. So basically you need the rotation axis for each point.
Therefore i first save the "original" center point for each point which is exactly on the circle. The tangent on that point is the cross product from the center point to (0,0,1). So you just have to rotate around that axis.
This node setup does that for you:

for simplification for the calculation i moved the global z-axis rotation after that rotation.
The storing of the center for each point is made after the mesh to points node:

whole node tree:

result:

Hope that helps. Happy blending.
Note: if you understand this setup, it should be very easy for you to add random offseted rotation to your points. I just wanted to keep it simple to make it easy to understand what's going on.

Thank you Chris that helps me a great deal, I can definitely move past my blockage with this.
Mucho thanks :)

de nada, you are welcome
